# Shuffle function in php

Tags: php

I have 4 variable each . 
I try to echo each variable with concatenation dot and shuffle them so, it is like that

```
echo str_shuffle(variable1.vatiable2.var3.var4)
```

When I echo the value of these variable the last two or one variable do not even appear so it echos like:

`Variable1.variable2` only and ignores the values at `variable3 and 4`, sometimes it only ignores the last variable only

Is the reason the shuffle function? How to solve this and is tere a similar function to shullke that does not produces this error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't concatenate like this. You can `implode()` them to a string if you want. But then if a value is longer then 1 char `str_shuffle()` will destroy the value. So you might want to look for `shuffle()`

Comment: What the *actual* content of the variables? Please make a working example showing `str_shuffle` not working. [**The code you posted works just fine, so that's all we can tell you**](https://eval.in/544328).

Comment: post real code. an MCVE.

Comment: Variable=(str_shuffle(value1value2 value3 etc.))

Comment: by MCVE @KarolyHorvath means a Minimal Complete Verfiable Example: http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Andrew38 please edit yor question rather than posting changes in comments.

Comment: @Andrew38 Actual content - that code would 1. never compile and 2. doesn't tell us what's in the different variables. Look at my linked example - you must be doing something wrong somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

```
$var='this';
$var1='pak';
$var2='ist';
$var3='pakistan';

$newvar= $var.$var1.$var2.$var3;

echo str_shuffle($newvar);
```

First concatenate all variables then store it new var and then shuffle it.